# What is the default timeout for Session and Channel in JSch library in java

Tags: java, connection, jsch

Does anyone know the default timeout for Session and Channel.

```
session.connect();
channel.connect();
```

I am going through the document but it doesn't explicitly say what is the default timeout ?

Answer (score 8):

For the `Channel`, the default timeout seems to be 20 seconds.

See the implementation of the `Channel.sendChannelOpen()`.

The timeout here defines, how long will the `connect()` wait for a response to open channel request. I'd say that the name of the method is confusing, it should be `open()`. You are not connecting anywhere (the session is already open).

---

For the `Session`, the default timeout is set using the `setTimeout()` method. If not set, the default default is 0, what means "infinite". Though there's always some last resort timeout on an OS-level.

The timeout here defines:

- How long will the `connect()` wait for the socket to open.
  Though this defines an upper limit only, to define a lower limit, see [JSch session timeout limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35009009/850848).
- Timeout for all future "reads" from the socket. See the [`Socket.SetSoTimeout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout-int-)
- It also affects a connection to a proxy, if there's any.