# Handling symbols with JSch authentication

Tags: java, scala, authentication, symbols, jsch

I am getting JSch authentication failure when my password contains characters like *, !. May I know if there is a list of characters that need to be escaped and what's the correct way to escape them?

For !, I tried `password = password.replace("!", "^!")` in scala and it works, but same doesn't work for *. If anyone faced similar issue or can guide me in this regard, it will be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: This is unlikely a problem of JSch as such, but rather about a way you provide credentials to JSch. But it's hard to answer that as you didn't show us any code. - Similarly to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53164471/850848), where you never told us that you are behind a proxy. - Next time you ask a question here, you need to provide a way more context.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, Martin. I will take this into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This works if I use URLEncoder to encode the password and decoder to decode it again.